# Function using multiprocessing returns None values

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, nonetype

I have been stuck on this for quite a while now. I am using the multiprocessing function to speed up a function that previously looped over data points. Before using multiprocessing the function worked fine, but now it returns some none values (the first few, <10) before returning values. I have tried many things and different ways to use the multiprocessing pool.

The multiprocessing is used inside a function, which I am not sure if that might be the problem?

```
def SkyViewFactor(point, coords, max_radius):
    betas_lin = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,steps_beta)
    """this is the analytical dome area but should make same assumption as for d_area"""
    dome_area = max_radius**2*2*np.pi
    """ we throw away all point outside the dome
    # dome is now a 5 column array of points:
    # the 5 columns: x,y,z,radius,angle theta"""
    dome_p = dome(point, coords, max_radius)
    betas = np.zeros(steps_beta)

    """we loop over all points in the dome"""
    d = 0
    while (d < dome_p.shape[0]):

        psi = np.arctan((dome_p[d,2]-point[2])/dome_p[d,3])
        """The angles of the min and max angle of the building"""
        beta_min = - np.arcsin(np.sqrt(2*gridboxsize**2)/2/dome_p[d,3]) + dome_p[d,4]
        beta_max = np.arcsin(np.sqrt(2*gridboxsize**2)/2/dome_p[d,3]) + dome_p[d,4]

        """Where the index of betas fall within the min and max beta, and there is not already a larger psi blocking"""
        betas[np.nonzero(np.logical_and((betas < psi), np.logical_and((beta_min <= betas_lin), (betas_lin < beta_max))))] = psi
        d +=1
    areas = d_area(betas, steps_beta, max_radius)
    """The SVF is the fraction of area of the dome that is not blocked"""
    SVF = np.around((dome_area - np.sum(areas))/dome_area, 3)
    #print(SVF)
    return SVF

def calc_SVF(coords, max_radius, blocklength):
    """
    Function to calculate the sky view factor.
    We create a dome around a point with a certain radius,
    and for each point in the dome we evaluate of the height of this point blocks the view
    :param coords: all coordinates of our dataset
    :param max_radius: maximum radius we think influences the svf
    :param blocklength: the first amount of points in our data set we want to evaluate
    :return: SVF for all points
    """


    def parallel_runs_SVF():
        points = [coords[i,:] for i in range(blocklength)]
        pool = Pool()
        SVF_list = []
        SVF_par = partial(SkyViewFactor, coords=coords,max_radius=max_radius) # prod_x has only one argument x (y is fixed to 10)
        SVF = pool.map(SVF_par, points)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        # if SVF != None:
        #     SVF_list.append(SVF)
        print(SVF)
        return SVF


    if __name__ == '__SVF__':
        return parallel_runs_SVF()
```

This function is later called in:

```
def reshape_SVF(data,coords,julianday,lat,long,LMT,reshape,save_CSV,save_Im):

    [x_len, y_len] = [int(data.shape[0]/2),int(data.shape[1]/2)]
    blocklength = int(x_len*y_len)

    "Compute SVF and SF and Reshape the shadow factors and SVF back to nd array"
    SVFs = calc_SVF(coords,max_radius,blocklength)
    SFs = calc_SF(coords,julianday,lat,long,LMT,blocklength)
    #SVFs = filter(None, SVFs)
    "If reshape is true we reshape the arrays to the original data matrix"
    if reshape == True:
        SVF_matrix = np.ndarray([x_len,y_len])
        SF_matrix = np.ndarray([x_len,y_len])
        for i in range(blocklength):
            SVF_matrix[coords[int(i-x_len/2),0],coords[int(i-y_len/2),1]]  = SVFs[i]
            SF_matrix[coords[int(i-x_len/2),0],coords[int(i-y_len/2),1]] = SFs[i]
        if save_CSV == True:
            np.savetxt("SVFmatrix.csv", SVF_matrix, delimiter=",")
            np.savetxt("SFmatrix.csv", SF_matrix, delimiter=",")
        if save_Im == True:
            tf.imwrite('SVF_matrix.tif', SVF_matrix, photometric='minisblack')
            tf.imwrite('SF_matrix.tif', SF_matrix, photometric='minisblack')
        return SF_matrix,SF_matrix

    elif reshape == False:
        np.savetxt("SVFs.csv", SVFs, delimiter=",")
        np.savetxt("SFs.csv", SFs, delimiter=",")
        return SVFs, SFs
```

SFs is a similar function with the same structure (it also uses multiprocessing). The goal is to return a list with all Sky View factors, or if reshape is true a matrix with the same shape as the original input data (DSM data) with the sky view factor for each location.

I get the error:
SVF_matrix[coords[int(i-x_len/2),0],coords[int(i-y_len/2),1]]  = SVFs[i]

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

I tried to filter out nones with the filter() function using

```
SVFs = filter(None, SVFs)
```

This returns the error
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Also I do not know if the None values returned are instead of the actual values or extra (i.e. if I have 1000 datapoints I should have 1000 sky view factors, but do I get an array with 3 Nones and then numbers, do I get 3 Nones ánd 1000 sky view factors or do I get a list of 1000 values of which the first 3 are Nones?)

I also tried to Make an empty list and append the SVF only if this is not None, this however also does not work

```
SVF_list = []
if SVF != None:
    SVF_list.append(SVF)
return SVF_list
```

To include all used functions: These are the functions used in SkyViewFactor to calculate distances and the area elements

```
def dist(point, coord):
    """
    :param point: evaluation point (x,y,z)
    :param coord: array of coordinates with heights
    :return: the distance from each coordinate to the point and the angle
    """
    # Columns is dx
    dx = (coord[:,1]-point[1])*gridboxsize
    # Rows is dy
    dy = (coord[:,0]-point[0])*gridboxsize
    dist = np.sqrt(abs(dx)**2 + abs(dy)**2)
    """angle is 0 north direction"""
    angle = np.arctan2(dy,dx)+np.pi/2
    return dist,angle

def dome(point, coords, maxR):
    """
    :param point: point we are evaluating
    :param coords: array of coordinates with heights
    :param maxR: maximum radius in which we think the coordinates can influence the SVF
    :return: a dome of points that we take into account to evaluate the SVF
    """

    radii, angles = dist(point,coords)
    coords = np.column_stack([coords, radii])
    coords = np.column_stack([coords, angles])
    """the dome consist of points higher than the view height and within the radius we want"""
    dome = coords[(np.logical_and(coords[:,3]<maxR,coords[:,3]>0.1)),:]
    dome = dome[(dome[:,2]>point[2]),:]
    return dome

def d_area(psi,steps_beta,maxR):

    """Radius at ground surface and at the height of the projection of the building"""
    d_area = 2*np.pi/steps_beta*maxR**2*np.sin(psi)
    return d_area
```

Help with this or some other suggestion to speed up my code / use multiprocessing the right way is very appreciated!

I am trying to speed up a for loop using multiprocessing, this works without multiprocessing but since I have to iterate over 1.250.000 datapoints it is way to slow. With multiprocessing it returns None for the first few values.

Comment: `calc_SVF` doesn't appear to return anything.

Comment: sorry i see the last part was not copied, the entire function is now in there

Comment: If `__name__` isn't `'__SVF__'`, it still won't return anything. Why do that?